# Modifying a class for a different paper size

Tags: cv, paper-size

I'm working on my cv based off the forty seconds class

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/forty-seconds-cv/pztcktmyngsk

It's originally made with A4 paper. But since that size is virtually non-existent here, I want to change it to letter, but when I change it on the class definition, it doesn't automatically rescale the page elements. How could I go about doing that?

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

On github https://github.com/PandaScience/FortySecondsCV it says:

*Class Options.
Possible options that can be passed to FortySecondsCV are:
all valid options for the ***standard article class*** like e.g. a4paper or 11pt.*

So check out https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/macros/latex/base/classes.pdf , i.e. normal US or UK paper formats should be possible too, like **letterpaper**.

So e.g.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{fortysecondscv}
```

should do the job.

**P.S.**: After having a closer look at the template, and taking into account a TODO-remark in the READ.ME ... up to now there probably is no automatic adjustment.

Instead, the preamble lists predefined and commented-out items:

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    % 9pt,
    % sidesectionsize=Large,
    % showframes,
    % vline=2.2em,
    % maincolor=cvgreen,
    % sidecolor=gray!50,
    % sidetextcolor=green,
    % sectioncolor=red,
    % subsectioncolor=orange,
    % itemtextcolor=black!80,
    % sidebarwidth=0.4\paperwidth,
    % topbottommargin=0.03\paperheight,
    % leftrightmargin=20pt,
    % profilepicsize=4.5cm,
    % profilepicborderwidth=3.5pt,
    % profilepicstyle=profilecircle,
    % profilepiczoom=1.0,
    % profilepicxshift=0mm,
    % profilepicyshift=0mm,
    % profilepicrounding=1.0cm,
    % logowidth=4.5cm,
    % logospace=5mm,
    % logoposition=before,
    % sidebarplacement=right,
]{fortysecondscv}

% fine tune line spacing
% \usepackage{setspace}
% \setstretch{1.1}
```

Unless you tried already, perhaps it's sufficient to remove some comment `%` or/and adjust the values as needed.

Comment: I already tried that, it works insofar as changing the paper size. However it doesn't rescale the elements to fit neatly.

Comment: @DDamian, please consider also reporting to the originator of this CV via github or via his website: https://pandascience.net/. If it's a problem from the package, there is probably little we can do here ...

Comment: @DDamian, please edit your question and add screenshots which show the problem. Thanks